# Include \lstlistoflistings as a caption of an appendix section

Tags: listings

I am using listings in my Latex file and would like to list all listings in a separate appendix section.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}          %dummy text
\usepackage{listings}               % used for source code inclusion

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext[1]

\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext

\lstset{frame=single, linewidth=16cm, breaklines=true}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Some listing, captionpos=b]
Test
\end{lstlisting}
\pagebreak

\appendix
\section{Would like to see caption here...}
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I would like to see the caption "Listings" right next to the appendix A-enumeration.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your document is not compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` loads package `tocbasic`. To use the features of `tocbasic` for the listings too, add

```
\usepackage{scrhack}
\setuptoc{lol}{numbered}
```

to your preamble. Then the List of Listings will be a numbered section:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\setuptoc{lol}{numbered}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext
\lstset{frame=single, linewidth=16cm, breaklines=true}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Some listing, captionpos=b]
Test
\end{lstlisting}
\clearpage
\appendix
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

---

This works with a standard class too. but then package `tocbasic` must be loaded too.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\setuptoc{lol}{numbered}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext
\lstset{frame=single, linewidth=16cm, breaklines=true}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Some listing, captionpos=b]
Test
\end{lstlisting}
\clearpage
\appendix
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]